# D3 - show/hide text of only clicked node

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to show/hide text of a node in D3 on click. I tried using the following code:

```
var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
  .data(json.nodes)
  (...)

node.on("click", function() {
  if (textShowing) {
    node.select("text").style("visibility", "hidden");
  } else {
    node.select("text").style("visibility", "visible");
  }
    textShowing = !textShowing;
 });
```

The code results in text property of **all** nodes showing/disappearing on click of any of those.

How can I affect the text property of only the clicked node?

Comment: Instead of `node.select("text")` do `d3.select(this).select("text")`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`node` is a selection containing all your groups (I suppose they are groups, since you didn't copy/paste the entire selection).

If you want to do anything only in the clicked group, you have to select it using `d3.select(this)`, which selects the current (in your case, the clicked) DOM element.

Thus, instead of:

```
node.select("text")
```

It should be:

```
d3.select(this).select("text")
```