# Creating a d3.js Treemap zoomable with CSV

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

I want to create a Treemap with d3 but the enitities I want to show don't have a hierarchy. Is it still possible to create a Treemap?

My data includes crimes in Germany.

The I just wanted to show in the beginning all the crimes (Treemap not zoomed). then if I click on one of the boxes it will show me how many of them are male or female.

Sounds so easy but I really don't get it with my example.

I have tried so many examples but I dont get it because of the hierarchy.

[First screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4nETS.png)

[Seccond Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OCS62.png)

Comment: "I have tried so many examples but I dont get it because of the hierarchy." well then you'll have to make one as an intermediate step between reading from file and drawing

Comment: But I don't know how :/ could you explain me how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can arrange tabular data in a hierarchy using `d3.nest()`. This function groups the data under multiple key fields, similar to a GROUP BY statement in SQL - more detail can be found in [the nest documentation](https://devdocs.io/d3~4/d3-collection#nests). For an introduction to using `d3.nest()`, see [this guide](http://bl.ocks.org/phoebebright/raw/3176159/).

D3's `treemap` requires data to be arranged in a hierarchy with a root node, so you should nest all table entries under a single 'root' value as well as any fields that you wish to use to subdivide the treemap. The following code will arrange your data into a hierarchy that splits it by Sexus only:

```
var nested_data = d3.nest()
    // Create a root node by nesting all data under the single value "root":
    .key(function () { return "root"; })
    // Nest by other fields of interest:
    .key(function (d) { return d.Sexus; })
    .entries(data);
```

For example, the following code shows a single rectangle in the treemap for all crimes and displays the number of crimes by Sexus when the user clicks on the rectangle:

```
<script src="js/d3.v4.js"></script>
<script>
    var margin = { top: 40, right: 10, bottom: 10, left: 10 },
        width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
        height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    var color = d3.scaleOrdinal().range(d3.schemeCategory20c);

    var treemap = d3.treemap().size([width, height]);

    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
        .attr("width", (width + margin.left + margin.right) + "px")
        .attr("height", (height + margin.top + margin.bottom) + "px");

    d3.csv("data/GermanyCrimeData.csv", function (error, data) {
        if (error) throw error;

        var nested_data = d3.nest()
            // Create a root node by nesting all data under the single value "root":
            .key(function () { return "root"; })
            // Nest by other fields of interest:
            .key(function (d) { return d.Sexus; })
            .entries(data);

        var root = d3.hierarchy(nested_data[0], function (d) { return d.values; })
            .sum(function (d) { return d.Tatverdaechtige_Insgesamt_deutsch; });

        var tree = treemap(root);

        var nodes = svg.selectAll(".node")
            .data([tree])  // Bind an array that contains the root node only.
          .enter().append("g")
            .attr("class", "node")
            .attr('transform', function (d) {
                return 'translate(' + [d.x0, d.y0] + ')'
            })
            .on("click", function () {
                d3.select(this).select("text").style("visibility", "visible");
                //See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44074031/d3-show-hide-text-of-only-clicked-node
            });

        nodes.append("rect")
            .attr("width", function (d) { return Math.max(0, d.x1 - d.x0 - 1) + "px"; })
            .attr("height", function (d) { return Math.max(0, d.y1 - d.y0 - 1) + "px"; })
            .attr("fill", function (d) { return color(d.data.key); });

        nodes.append("text")
            .attr("dx", 4)
            .attr("dy", 14)
            .style("visibility", "hidden")  //Initially the text is not visible
            .text(function (d) {
                // Create an array of Tatverdaechtige_Insgesamt_deutsch counts for each Sexus:
                var array = d.children.map(function (elt) {  // Here, map is a native Javascript function, not a D3 function
                    // Return "Sexus: Tatverdaechtige_Insgesamt_deutsch":
                    return elt.data.key + ": " + elt.value;
                    // Note that d.data.key and d.value were created by d3.nest()
                });
                // Return a string representation of the array:
                return d.data.key + " - " + array.join(", ");
            });
    });
</script>
```

To subdivide the treemap by a given field, the data must be nested by that field and `tree.children` must be bound to the DOM instead of `[tree]`:

```
    //...
    d3.csv("data/GermanyCrimeData.csv", function (error, data) {
        if (error) throw error;

        var nested_data = d3.nest()
            .key(function () { return "root"; })
            .key(function (d) { return d.Straftat; })
            .key(function (d) { return d.Sexus; })
            .entries(data);

        var root = d3.hierarchy(nested_data[0], function (d) { return d.values; })
            .sum(function (d) { return d.Tatverdaechtige_Insgesamt_deutsch; });

        var tree = treemap(root);

        var nodes = svg.selectAll(".node")
            .data(tree.children)  // Bind the children of the tree's root node
          .enter().append("g")
            .attr("class", "node")
            .attr('transform', function (d) {
                return 'translate(' + [d.x0, d.y0] + ')'
            })
            .on("click", function () {
                d3.select(this).select("text").style("visibility", "visible");
                //See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44074031/d3-show-hide-text-of-only-clicked-node
            });

        //...
```

A simple way to make the treemap zoomable is to place the code that draws the treemap in a function, then use `on("click", ...)` to re-trigger the function whenever a rectangle is clicked, zooming in on the chosen node:

```
    //...
    d3.csv("data/GermanyCrimeData.csv", function (error, data) {
        if (error) throw error;

        var nested_data = d3.nest()
            .key(function () { return "root"; })
            .key(function (d) { return d.Stadt_Landkreis; })
            .key(function (d) { return d.Straftat; })
            .key(function (d) { return d.Sexus; })
            .entries(data);


        function drawTreemap(root) {

            var hierarchical_data = d3.hierarchy(root, function (d) { return d.values; })
                .sum(function (d) { return d.Tatverdaechtige_Insgesamt_deutsch; });

            var tree = treemap(hierarchical_data);

            // Clear the contents of the <svg>:
            svg.selectAll("*").remove();

            // Now populate the <svg>:

            var nodes = svg.selectAll(".node")
                .data(tree.children)  //Bind the children of the root node in the tree
              .enter().append("g")
                .attr("class", "node")
                .attr('transform', function (d) {
                    return 'translate(' + [d.x0, d.y0] + ')'
                })
                .on("click", function (d) {
                    if (d.children) {  //The user clicked on a node that has children
                        drawTreemap(d.data);
                    } else {  // The user clicked on a node that has no children (i.e. a leaf node).
                        // Do nothing.
                    }
                });

            nodes.append("rect")
                .attr("width", function (d) { return Math.max(0, d.x1 - d.x0 - 1) + "px"; })
                .attr("height", function (d) { return Math.max(0, d.y1 - d.y0 - 1) + "px"; })
                .attr("fill", function (d) { return color(d.data.key); });

            nodes.append("text")
                .attr("dx", 4)
                .attr("dy", 14)
                //.style("visibility", "hidden")  //Initially the text is not visible
                .text(function (d) {
                    if (d.children) {
                        return d.data.key;
                    } else {
                        return d.data.Stadt_Landkreis + ", "
                               + d.data.Straftat + ", "
                               + d.data.Sexus + ": "
                               + d.data.Tatverdaechtige_Insgesamt_deutsch;
                    }
                });

        };  // end of drawTreemap()

        // Now call drawTreemap for the first time:
        drawTreemap(nested_data[0]);
    });
</script>
```

Finally, to animate the transitions, the following code is a zoomable treemap based on [Mike Bostock's example](https://bost.ocks.org/mike/treemap/), where `flare.json` has been replaced with the data from your CSV file, arranged with `d3.nest()` and  `d3.hierarchy()` (this example uses D3 v3):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>

        #chart {
            width: 960px;
            height: 500px;
            background: #ddd;
        }

        text {
            pointer-events: none;
        }

        .grandparent text {
            font-weight: bold;
        }

        rect {
            fill: none;
            stroke: #fff;
        }

            rect.parent,
            .grandparent rect {
                stroke-width: 2px;
            }

        .grandparent rect {
            fill: orange;
        }

        .grandparent:hover rect {
            fill: #ee9700;
        }

        .children rect.parent,
        .grandparent rect {
            cursor: pointer;
        }

        .children rect.parent {
            fill: #bbb;
            fill-opacity: .5;
        }

        .children:hover rect.child {
            fill: #bbb;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <script src="js/d3.v3.js"></script>
    <script>

    var margin = {top: 20, right: 0, bottom: 0, left: 0},
        width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
        height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom,
        formatNumber = d3.format(",d"),
        transitioning;

    var x = d3.scale.linear()
        .domain([0, width])
        .range([0, width]);

    var y = d3.scale.linear()
        .domain([0, height])
        .range([0, height]);

    var treemap = d3.layout.treemap()
        .children(function(d, depth) { return depth ? null : d._children; })
        .sort(function(a, b) { return a.value - b.value; })
        .ratio(height / width * 0.5 * (1 + Math.sqrt(5)))
        .round(false);

    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
        .attr("id", "chart")  // Apply the #chart style to the <svg> element
        .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr("height", height + margin.bottom + margin.top)
        .style("margin-left", -margin.left + "px")
        .style("margin.right", -margin.right + "px")
      .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")")
        .style("shape-rendering", "crispEdges");

    var grandparent = svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "grandparent");

    grandparent.append("rect")
        .attr("y", -margin.top)
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", margin.top);

    grandparent.append("text")
        .attr("x", 6)
        .attr("y", 6 - margin.top)
        .attr("dy", ".75em");

    d3.csv("data/GermanyCrimeData.csv", function (error, data) {
        if (error) throw error;

        var nested_data = d3.nest()
            .key(function () { return "root"; })
            .key(function (d) { return d.Stadt_Landkreis; })
            .key(function (d) { return d.Straftat; })
            .key(function (d) { return d.Sexus; })
            .entries(data);

        // In D3 v3, the syntax for arranging the data in a hierarchy is different:
        var my_hierarchy = d3.layout.hierarchy()
            .children(function (d) { return d.values; })
            .value(function (d) { return d.Tatverdaechtige_Insgesamt_deutsch; });

        // Apply the hierarchy to the nested data:
        my_hierarchy(nested_data[0]);  // This changes nested_data in-place

        var root = nested_data[0];

        initialize(root);
        // my_hierarchy() has already added the aggregate values to each node
        // in the tree, so instead we only need to add d._children to each node:
        addUnderscoreChildren(root);
        layout(root);
        display(root);

      function initialize(root) {
        root.x = root.y = 0;
        root.dx = width;
        root.dy = height;
        root.depth = 0;
      }

      // NEW FUNCTION:
      function addUnderscoreChildren(d) {
        if (d.children) {
            // d has children
            d._children = d.children;
            d.children.forEach(addUnderscoreChildren);
        }
      }

      /* NOT NEEDED:
      // Aggregate the values for internal nodes. This is normally done by the
      // treemap layout, but not here because of our custom implementation.
      // We also take a snapshot of the original children (_children) to avoid
      // the children being overwritten when when layout is computed.
      function accumulate(d) {
        return (d._children = d.children)
            ? d.value = d.children.reduce(function(p, v) { return p + accumulate(v); }, 0)
            : d.value;
      }*/

      // Compute the treemap layout recursively such that each group of siblings
      // uses the same size (1×1) rather than the dimensions of the parent cell.
      // This optimizes the layout for the current zoom state. Note that a wrapper
      // object is created for the parent node for each group of siblings so that
      // the parent’s dimensions are not discarded as we recurse. Since each group
      // of sibling was laid out in 1×1, we must rescale to fit using absolute
      // coordinates. This lets us use a viewport to zoom.
      function layout(d) {
        if (d._children) {
          treemap.nodes({_children: d._children});
          d._children.forEach(function(c) {
            c.x = d.x + c.x * d.dx;
            c.y = d.y + c.y * d.dy;
            c.dx *= d.dx;
            c.dy *= d.dy;
            c.parent = d;
            layout(c);
          });
        }
      }

      function display(d) {
        grandparent
            .datum(d.parent)
            .on("click", transition)
          .select("text")
            .text(name(d));

        var g1 = svg.insert("g", ".grandparent")
            .datum(d)
            .attr("class", "depth");

        var g = g1.selectAll("g")
            .data(d._children)
          .enter().append("g");

        g.filter(function(d) { return d._children; })
            .classed("children", true)
            .on("click", transition);

        g.selectAll(".child")
            .data(function(d) { return d._children || [d]; })
          .enter().append("rect")
            .attr("class", "child")
            .call(rect);

        g.append("rect")
            .attr("class", "parent")
            .call(rect)
          .append("title")
            .text(function(d) { return formatNumber(d.value); });

        g.append("text")
            .attr("dy", ".75em")
            // Replace d.name with d.key; use a function to provide 
            // a key for leaf nodes, because nest() does not set their
            // 'key' property:
            .text(function(d) { return d.key || keyOfLeafNode(d); })  
            .call(text);

        // NEW FUNCTION:
        function keyOfLeafNode(d) {
            return d.Stadt_Landkreis + " "
                + d.Straftat + " "
                + d.Sexus + ": "
                + d.value;
        }

        function transition(d) {
          if (transitioning || !d) return;
          transitioning = true;

          var g2 = display(d),
              t1 = g1.transition().duration(750),
              t2 = g2.transition().duration(750);

          // Update the domain only after entering new elements.
          x.domain([d.x, d.x + d.dx]);
          y.domain([d.y, d.y + d.dy]);

          // Enable anti-aliasing during the transition.
          svg.style("shape-rendering", null);

          // Draw child nodes on top of parent nodes.
          svg.selectAll(".depth").sort(function(a, b) { return a.depth - b.depth; });

          // Fade-in entering text.
          g2.selectAll("text").style("fill-opacity", 0);

          // Transition to the new view.
          t1.selectAll("text").call(text).style("fill-opacity", 0);
          t2.selectAll("text").call(text).style("fill-opacity", 1);
          t1.selectAll("rect").call(rect);
          t2.selectAll("rect").call(rect);

          // Remove the old node when the transition is finished.
          t1.remove().each("end", function() {
            svg.style("shape-rendering", "crispEdges");
            transitioning = false;
          });
        }

        return g;
      }

      function text(text) {
        text.attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.x) + 6; })
            .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.y) + 6; });
      }

      function rect(rect) {
        rect.attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.x); })
            .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.y); })
            .attr("width", function(d) { return x(d.x + d.dx) - x(d.x); })
            .attr("height", function(d) { return y(d.y + d.dy) - y(d.y); });
      }

      function name(d) {
        // d3.nest() gives each node the property 'key' instead of 'name',
        // so replace 'd.name' with 'd.key':
        return d.parent
            ? name(d.parent) + "." + d.key
            : d.key;
      }
    });

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```